# Why we shift zero-frequency component to center of spectrum of an image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, fft

```
F = round(fftshift(abs(fft2(A))))
```

where A is the image.

I am studying contrast stretching in Digital Image Processing. I don't understand zero frequency component. I searched for it but I couldn't understand it, kindly refer some documentation about zero frequency component.

Comment: This isn't clear - `fftshift` shifts *all* components.

Comment: why we Shift zero-frequency component to center of spectrum of an image?

Comment: i have shown code for the purpose that this is not a homework question.

Comment: Imagine a signal y(t) = 3 + sin(t)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The zero-frequency is shifted to the center in both audio and image spectrums, simply because this is how people normally expect to see a spectrum. I.e. it is per convention. The spectrum content is not changed in any way, and everything you can derive after the shift, you can derive before the shift.

And Oliver is right - all frequencies are shifted and the zero-frequency (DC) just is the one ending up in the center.

Regards